# swipe view using UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

hi all freind i want ask somthing, i try use label to swipe between views but i cant know the problem?

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe;
swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(Gest_SwipedLeft:)];
[swipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[label addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
[swipe release];


-(void)Gest_SwipedLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender{
      ThirdQPage* y=[[ThirdQPage alloc]init];
[self.view.superview addSubview:[y view]];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];}
```

Comment: i want swipe between my view controller

Comment: and i want use labe to swap left and rayt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this -

```
- (void)hideView:(NSTimer *)timer
{    
    UIView *currentView = (UIView *)[timer userInfo];
    [currentView addSubview:self.yourNewView];
    return;
}

-(void)Gest_SwipedLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                           forView:yourCurrentView cache:YES];

    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 
                                     target:self 
                                   selector:@selector(hideView:) 
                                   userInfo:yourCurrentView 
                                    repeats:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

You can use the same logic to swipe back from your `newView` to `oldView`.

Comment: i not want use timer ,i want use label to change between view

Answer (score 0):

Set `label.userInteractionEnabled = YES`. The default value for `UILabel` is `NO`, therefore all touches are ignored.

> userInteractionEnabled A Boolean value that determines whether user
>   events are ignored and removed from the event queue.
>
> @property(nonatomic, getter=isUserInteractionEnabled) BOOL
>   userInteractionEnabled
>
> Discussion This property is inherited from the
>   UIView parent class. This class changes the default value of this
>   property to NO.